# Get a specific text from a text file using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I’ve got a text file named ‘Settings.txt’
Within the file I have “Access: False”
Am I able to grab the text after ‘Access:’ to see what they have inputted?

Here is what I have tried:

```
for /f "token=2 delims=:" %%L in (Settings.txt) do (if %%L==True goto Start ELSE FALSE goto Fail )
```

Comment: The `IF...ELSE` syntax is clearly defined in the help file for the `IF` command.  You can read the help file for any command by opening a command prompt and typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. `IF /?`

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate `findstr` and also you did not use `else` correctly.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%i in ('type "settings.txt" ^| findstr /i "Access:"') do (
   if /i "%%i" == "True" (
     goto :start
   ) else (
     goto :fail
 )
)
```

Obviously there are easier ways, this example does not need `else` it will fall through to `start` if the value is `True` else it will skip that label and goto `fail` label:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%i in ('type "settings.txt" ^| findstr /i "Access:"') do if /i not "%%i" == "True" goto :fail
:start
echo do start stuff here:
goto :eof
:fail
echo do fail stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check for the word `Access` (unless there is only one line in `Settings.txt`), to add the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> behind the `:` to the list of delimiters, and you will need to adapt the `if` syntax and probably make it case-insensitive (`/I`):

```cmd
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%K in ("Settings.txt") do (
    if /I "%%K"=="Access" if /I "%%L"=="True" (goto Start) else if /I "%%L"=="False" (goto Fail)
)
```

Which can be rewritten as this (to make the `if` blocks more obvious):

```cmd
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%K in ("Settings.txt") do (
    if /I "%%K"=="Access" (
        if /I "%%L"=="True" (
            goto Start
        ) else (
            if /I "%%L"=="False" (
                goto Fail
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Appreciate it. :)

Comment: Great! Please consider to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that helped you most (it doesn't have to be mine)…